# Facebook share button does not show up

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to add a very basic facebook share button as it is suggested here :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button?locale=fr_FR

The problem is the button does not simply show up, no javascript or network errors.

Can anyone say me what i'm doing wrong ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>titre</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line tells you to add the sdk javascript which you havent done. Do the following and you should be good to go:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Location of SDK javascript"></script>
```

Comment: i will do it in 4 minutes ;)

Comment: This script tag is not present in the code example, or anywhere in the FB SDK documentation. That's the reason you couldn't provide the location in your example. Web devs shouldn't have to guess or search to put a blimming button on their web page, just because the code examples are incomplete. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button#example

Comment: This is a silly answer... the facebook script is a script loader itself. It loads the javascript SDK it needs by inserting a script tag into the document.

Answer (score 10):

The marked answer is silly. The javascript included in the code is what loads the SDK javascript.

The problem I faced was that I was looking at the html page without going through a web server. In other words, I was using the file:// protocol and the facebook SDK doesn't work when run under that protocol. Although it does pull a lot of stuff in and affect the DOM, the Facebook share button does not show up.

Setting it up to run through a true web server on just localhost (in my case, IIS) and lo-and-behold the button shows up. Hopefully that will help some folks.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was the size attribute that prevented the button from showing.

Just add

```
data-size="large"
```

to the div tag for the button and it shows.

BTW, based on the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button), there is no medium size avaialable.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes these problems with seeing Facebook buttons is because of browser extensions like Disconnect that block scripts communicating with Facebook etc, so whitelist your site if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add "http:" to url in addition to changing "sdk.js" to "all.js" as suggested above, i.e:

Instead of:

js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1";

Use:

js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";

Good Luck

Answer (score -1):

STEP 1: Get a Facebook App ID for the domain the Share Button will live on.
STEP 2: Add the Facebook JavaScript SDK to your Web page.
STEP 3: Add code to load the jQuery library on your Web page
STEP 4: Add some jQuery and fb.ui code to display the Share dialog box